# If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$, the angles made by a vector with $x, y, z$ axes, are in the ratio 1:2:3 then their values are?

Tags: vectors, 3d

This is a question asked in a book:

> If $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are angles made by a vector $x, y, z$ axes respectively, and $\alpha$:$\beta$:$\gamma$ = 1:2:3 then values of $\alpha$, $\beta$, $\gamma$ are?

I tried the obvious by taking  $\alpha$ = k; $\beta$=2k; $\gamma$ = 3k; and substituting in  $cos^2\alpha$+$cos^2\beta$+$cos^2\gamma$ = 1

but its complicating things. I'm must be missing something simple and obvious but I can't figure out what.

Comment: you mean that the coordinates of the vector are $(x,y,z)$ ?

Comment: @JeanMarie I think they mean the vector makes angle $\alpha$ with the $x$-axis, angle $\beta$ with the $y$-axis, and angle $\gamma$ with the $z$-axis.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If
$\cos^2 x +\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)=1
$,
then,
since
$\cos^2(z)
=(\cos(2z)+1)/2
$,
$1
=(\cos(2x)+\cos(4x)+\cos(6x)+3)/2
$
or
$\cos(2x)+\cos(4x)+\cos(6x)
= -1
$.

Letting
$y = 2x$,

$\begin{array}\\
-1
&=\cos(y)+\cos(2y)+\cos(3y)\\
&=\cos(y)+2\cos^2y-1+4\cos^3(y)-3\cos(y)\\
&=4\cos^3(y)+2\cos^2y-2\cos(y)-1\\
\end{array}
$

or
$4\cos^3(y)+2\cos^2y-2\cos(y)
=0
$.

Letting
$z = \cos y$,

$\begin{array}\\
0
&=2z^3+2z^2-z\\
&=z(2z^2+z-1)\\
&=z(z+1)(2z-1)
\qquad\text{just fixed an error here}\\
\end{array}
$

so
$z = 0, -1, \frac12
$.

Therefore
$y=\pi/2, \pi, \pi/3$
so
$x
= y/2
=\pi/4, \pi/2, \pi/6
$.

Comment: The case $x=\pi/2$ give vector: (0,-1,0) which does not look a "true" solution...

Comment: But it does satisfy the condition.

Comment: [+1] You are right. Besides, your solution is perfectly clear.

Answer (score 0):

Taking vector $(\cos(30°),\sin(30°),0)=(\sqrt{3}/2,1/2,0)$, you get the angles $30°, 60°, 90°.$

Comment: Although you came up with the right angles (no pun intended), I get the impression there isn't a general technique provided in this post.  You seem just to know what vector will make the appropriate angles, but perhaps I've overlooked a subtlety here.

Comment: @hardmath Here is the way I have found this result: I began by asking myself what 2D problem would be equivalent, then I thought to the ratio 30° : 60°, and it appeared to me the evidence that I could use the 90° by stahing in the $xy$ plane, that's all.

Comment: Okay, it makes sense to consider a 2D solution for the sake of simplicity.  It might be worth adding a note to your Answer that this is possible if and only if $\alpha+\beta=\gamma$.

Answer (score 0):

It seems to me that we cannot avoid to solve the equation
$$
\cos^2 x +\cos^2(2x)+\cos^2(3x)=1
$$
For $x$ between $0$ and $\pi/2$ [Wolfram Alpha](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input/?i=cos%5E2%20x%2Bcos%5E2%282x%29%2Bcos%5E2%283x%29%3D1) gives the solution $x=\frac{\pi}{4}$ (that is an obvious solution).